# Prove Lucas numbers and Fibonacci numbers relation $F_n = \frac{L_{n - 1} + L_{n + 1}}{5}$

Tags: induction

$F_n$, is the $n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence.

$L_n$ is the $n$th Lucas number.

I want to prove that $F_n = \dfrac{L_{n-1}+L_{n+1}}5 $.

Things I know:

1. $L_n$+$L_{n+1}=L_{n+2}$
2. $F_{n-1} + F_{n+1}=L_n$.

The base case is easy to prove. I will omit proving the base case it is simple.

My attempt:

$F_{n+1} = \dfrac{L_{n}+L_{n+2}}5 $.

Attempt one :using and manipulating $#2$ make all $L_n$ in terms of $F_n$.

Attempt two:

Using $#2$ two make $F_{n+1}$ in terms of $L_n$.

Comment: how about using the explicit expression for both Fibonacci and Lucas (the latter I assume it exists), and you check the equality directly?

Comment: Prove two base cases. Have two hypothesis steps, $P(k-1)$ and $P(k)$. Then, add both of them to get P(k+1)$

Comment: @Chip  An explicit formula for the Fibonacci numbers is $$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$ for $n \geq 1$, where $$\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ and $$\psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$  An explicit formula for the Lucas numbers is $$L_n = \varphi^n + \psi^n$$ for $n \geq 0$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are defined as above.

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci numbers are defined recursively by 
$$
F_n = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n = 1$}\\
1 & \text{if $n = 2$}\\
F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2} & \text{if $n > 2$}
\end{cases}
$$
and the Lucas numbers are defined recursively by 
$$
L_n =
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $n = 0$}\\
1 & \text{if $n = 1$}\\
L_{n - 1} + L_{n - 2} & \text{if $n > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

**Proof.**  Let $P(n)$ the statement 
$$F_n = \frac{L_{n + 1} + L_{n - 1}}{5}$$
We will prove $P(n)$ holds for all positive integers $n$ using strong induction.

Let $n = 1$.  Observe that $L_2 = L_1 + L_0 = 1 + 2 = 3$. Thus, 
$$\frac{L_{1 + 1} + L_{1 - 1}}{5} = \frac{L_2 + L_0}{5} = \frac{3 + 2}{5} = \frac{5}{5} = 1 = F_1$$
so $P(1)$ holds.

Let $n = 2$.  Observe that $L_3 = L_2 + L_1 = 3 + 1 = 4$.  Thus,
$$\frac{L_{2 + 1} + L_{2 - 1}}{5} = \frac{L_3 + L_1}{5} = \frac{4 + 1}{5} = \frac{5}{5} = 1 = F_2$$
so $P(2)$ also holds.

Assume $P(n)$ holds for each positive integer $n \leq m$, where $m \geq 2$.  Then 
$$F_m = \frac{L_{m + 1} + L_{m - 1}}{5}$$
and 
$$F_{m - 1} = \frac{L_{(m - 1) + 1} + L_{(m - 1) - 1}}{5} = \frac{L_m + L_{m - 2}}{5}$$

Let $n = m + 1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{L_{(m + 1) + 1} + L_{(m + 1) - 1}}{5} & = \frac{L_{m + 2} + L_{m}}{5}\\
& = \frac{L_{m + 1} + L_m + L_{m - 1} + L_{m - 2}}{5}\\
& = \frac{L_{m + 1} + L_{m - 1} + L_m + L_{m - 2}}{5}\\
& = \frac{L_{m + 1} + L_{m - 1}}{5} + \frac{L_m + L_{m - 2}}{5}\\
& = F_m + F_{m - 1}\\
& = F_{m + 1}
\end{align*}
Thus, $P(n)$ holds for each positive integer $n$.$\blacksquare$